# How to register Additional Hooks in a NuxtJs project with Vue Class Component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-class-components

I am building my first [NuxtJs](https://nuxtjs.org/) project and I am also using [Vue Class Component](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) to write my components as classes.

I am facing trouble in accessing the `beforeRouteEnter` component hook after applying Vue Class Component (it doesn't get called anymore). So I found the documentation about registering [aditional hooks](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/additional-hooks.html) when using this library, but I couldn't figure it out where to place the import statement in my NuxtJs structure.

I have this file (the same from docs):

```js
// class-component-hooks.js
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

// Register the router hooks with their names
Component.registerHooks([
  'beforeRouteEnter',
  'beforeRouteLeave',
  'beforeRouteUpdate'
])
```

And I would appreciate some help on how to set it in my NuxtJs project:

```js
// Where should I place this?
import './class-component-hooks'
```

Answer (score 0):

It tourned out to be quite simple:

I have placed the .js file inside a `plugins` folder:

```
// plugins/class-component-hooks.js
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

// Register the router hooks with their names
Component.registerHooks([
  'beforeRouteEnter',
  'beforeRouteLeave',
  'beforeRouteUpdate'
])
```

Then at my `nuxt.config.js` file, I placed this line:

```
...
  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/class-component-hooks.js", mode: "client" },
  ],
...
```